# NS Notification Confused Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, nsnotificationcenter

Currently in the process of implementing NS Notification in to my first IOS application. I am wanting to use it so when a user succesfully makes a purchase, the product name is broad cast out, and the listener runs the method to unlock the products. Looking at tutorials i am confused about how it works and would really appreciate if these could be cleared up. I will post the code below and what i think it does, if their are any mistakes please point these out.

Line 1 - Let is a variable that can not be changed, NotificationName is the name of the variable. Notfication.Name is declaring the name as "Notification Identifier"

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier")
```

Line 2 - I think here the "NotificationName" is the id of this for the listener as defined above by the let. 
If i want to pass in an object is this done at the end?  via the object tag. IE object: productsRequest

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

Line - 3 This is the listener, the notification name has to match the post to receive the correct notification i assume. The add observer self selector is confusing me, and if i pass in an object from the post  line 2 above, ie Object Products Request. Does this have to be declared in the listener?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification), name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

Any explanations to further my understanding are appreciated. Sorry if these seems like a basic question, how ever reading tutorials i am struggling to understand certain elements of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct.
2. Correct. The object you pass into postNotification method is a sender, which can be used to filter notifications with the same name (p.3)
3. When you subscribe for a specific notification and pass an object to `addObserver` method, you will receive only notifications which were sent with this exact object. If you don't specify it in `addObserver` you will receive all notifications with this name.
4. Don't forget to `removeObserver` as soon as you don't need to listen to them anymore. If your listener is a view controller, it is usually a good practice to `addObserver` in `viewWillAppear` and `removeObserver` in `viewDidDisappear` methods.